# angularJs : ng-template inside ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have lot of small template, so i put them in a single html file.

`smallTemlates.html`

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
...
</script>
```

then i include `smallTemlates.html` inside `index.html`.

`index.html`

```
  <body  ng-app="myapp" id="my-app">
      <div ng-include="'pathTo/smallTemlates.html'"></div>
</body>
```

then i tried to access these templates inside my controller/service using $templateRequest, but it is throwing 404 error.

```
  $templateRequest(component.popoverTemplateUrl).then(function(html) {  
     var template = html // 404 error
  });
```

but if i added these template direclty into `index.html` like below it works just fine.

```
 <body  ng-app="myapp" id="my-app">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
...
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
...
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you check the DOM for the 'smallTemlates.html' content is available or not?

Comment: @DhanaSekar yes it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **$templateCache** instead of ***$templateRequest***, because you don't need to make another request for template. ng-include already does this by default.

You have to wait for next digest to get the content for template:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$templateCache,$timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
    var template = $templateCache.get('smallTemlates.html').then(function(html){
        console.log("smallTemlates");
        console.log(html.data); 
       $timeout(function(){
           var template1 = $templateCache.get('template1.html');
             console.log("template1");
             console.log(template1); 
       });
    });

  });
});
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <div ng-include="'smallTemlates.html'"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

smallTemplates.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
template1zzasdfasdf
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
template2
</script>
```

[Plunker Link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0IC9kIX65GpgTQ5z2MHF?p=preview) (check console for the results)

Comment: @farhanlatheef glad to help :-)